# How to stop generating msg and srv for certain languages

Tags: ros, catkin, ros-kinetic, message-generation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed ROS tutorials where I generated msg and srv and everything worked well.

However, I saw that message_generation creates msgs and srvs not only for Python and C++ as I expected, but also for NodeJS, common-lisp and eusLisp. How can I "turn off" this? I need only Python and C++ types. I searched CMakeLists.txt but couldn't find anything related to these languages.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260865/how-to-stop-generating-msg-and-srv-for-certain-languages/) by [Freethinking](https://answers.ros.org/users/30231/freethinking/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-05-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see #q213511.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2